# HOW TO EDIT CUSTOM OPTIONS SELECT BOX IN MAGENTO 2

Tags: magento2, custom-options

I have one Customizable Option on my site and shows at the frontend of the product page.

-- The condition is when a custom pack is found as an input tag in which the customer adds the pack & pc, When a customer updates a pack, the amount of the package should also be updated in real-time.
-- For example, The price of 100 packs is $9.95, so if a customer buys 500 packs, the price should be picked and the product should be charted.
Add to cart data:- product name, 500pack and price

[image]

[image]